# find the dimension of a particular subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

choose the correct statement

1. either equal to 1 or equal to 4
2. less than or equal to 3
3. greater than or equal to 2
4. either equal to 0 or equal to 4

My attempts;  dimension of $\mathbb{R}^4 = \dim(\mathbb{R}^4) = 4$.  It given that $W$ is the subspace .

so dimension of $W$ must be equal to $4$ because  here  maximum number of linearly

independent vectors that is $(v_1,v_2,v_3, v_4 )$ in a subspace is $4$.  so my answer

is ...option A that is  it will either equal to $1$ or equal to $4$

Is my answer is correct or not. Please verified and tell me the solution i would be more thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The fact that $\sum_{i=1}^{4}v_{i}^{(j)}=0$ for all $j$ implies that the $v_{i}$'s are *linearly dependent*. Thus, what can you say about $\dim(\operatorname{span}(v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4}))$? Can the dimension ever be $4$?

Comment: im not getting @ervx,,,can u more elaborate pliz?

Comment: What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: how can i find dim (span(V1,v2,v3,v4 )..? im not able to find out ?

Comment: Since the four vectors $v_{1},\ldots,v_{4}$ are linearly dependent vectors in $W$, they cannot form a basis for $W$. However, they do span $W$ and hence some subcollection of $\{v_{1},\ldots,v_{4}\}$ must span $W$ since every spanning set can be reduced to a basis. Thus, $\dim W\leq 3$.